# Changing href for modal pop up with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using joomla!, i have a button that enables a form to pop out from the side when clicked.  I want to be able to change the href for a screen size less than 600px so that instead of using the pop up it redirects the user to the contact page.

I have added this jquery:

```
    jQuery(function(){
  var hrefs = ['contact-us', '#'];

  jQuery(window).on('resize', function() {
    jQuery('.case-study-signoff').prop('href', function() {
      return hrefs[jQuery(window).width() < 600 ? 0 : 1];

    });
  }).trigger('resize');
});
```

The previous jquery successfully changes the href as i can see in the html however nothing happens if you click it. You can right click and open in new tab which takes you to the desired contact page but not when clicked.

Comment: I would suggest to simply add both versions of the link to your html and only display one depending on the screen size. This is very easily achievable via CSS.

Comment: I thought that but wasn't sure about having a hidden link, whether it would be detrimental to SEO

Comment: Site address is:http://multi.multi-web-service.co.uk/ecommerce-websites

Comment: You are changing the HREF attribute of your link, but that doesn't really matter. What you have to change is the onClick event listener based on your resolution. The event listener determines what actually happens when you click the on the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this on your site and it seems to work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.case-study-signoff').off().click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (jQuery(window).width() < 600) {
            window.location = '/contact-us';
        } else {
            pwebContact177.toggleForm();
        }
    });
});
```

This code does the following:

1. Waits before the document is fully loaded
2. Removes the default event handlers from your '<- Contact Us' button.
3. Adds a new CLICK event handler
4. When you click on the button the code checks the width of the screen
5. If width < 600 then redirect to /contact-us
6. Else toggle the pop up with the contact form.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am pretty new to javascript so forgive me if these are stupid questions. The pop up is triggered via a css class that links to a joomla module. So would this still work?

Comment: @ADRIAN, I've done some digging in your website and found that the code that toggles the contact form is this: pwebContact177.toggleForm(); I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: Thanks. No its on the services pages, on the bottom there is a paragraph with contact us (styled to look like a button).
I have pasted your new jquery in and edited the selector to the class .case-study-signoff (which is what the 'button' has associated with it). 

This now works in terms of redirecting to the contact page below 600px but when above 600px the button does nothing.

Comment: Oh, i see the problem. It doesn't work because the code is executed too early. I've Modified the code in my answer again, it should hopefully work this time.

Comment: Hey, I am hoping you can help me again please. I have used the exact javascript code again for a different site: http://signfit.multi-web-services.co.uk/shop-signs
However the button for the pop out form and the contact us link again doesnt work above the required width, which I have set for 767 pixels this time.

Comment: @ADRIAN, please create a new question.